# Exit code 191 when running a python script to run a shell file

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix, exit-code

I'm trying to use a python script to run a series of oommf simulations on a unix cluster but I'm getting stuck at the point where I send a command from python to bash. I'm using the line:-

```
subprocess.check_call('qsub shellfile.sh')
```

Which returns exit code 191. What is exit code 191, I can't seem to be able to find it online. It may be a PBS error rather than a unix error but I'm not sure. The error doesn't seem to be in the shell file itself since the only commands in there:-

> #!/bin/bash
>
> # This is an example submit script for the hello world program.
>
> # OPTIONS FOR PBS PRO ==============================================================
>
> #PBS -l walltime=1:00:00
>
> # This specifies the job should run for no longer than 24 hours
>
> #PBS -l select=1:ncpus=8:mem=2048mb
>
> # This specifies the job needs 1 'chunk', with 1 CPU core, and 2048 MB of RAM (memory).
>
> #PBS -j oe
>
> # This joins up the error and output into one file rather that making two files
>
> ##PBS -o $working_folder/$PBS_JOBID-oommf_log
>
> # This send your output to the file "hello_output" rather than the standard filename
>
> # OPTIONS FOR PBS PRO ==============================================================
>
> #PBS -P HPCA-000987-EFR
>
> #PBS -M ppxsb3@nottingham.ac.uk
>
> #PBS -m abe
>
> # Here we just use Unix command to run our program
>   echo "Running on `hostname`"
>
> sleep 20
>
> echo "Finished job now""

Which should just print the hostname and 'Finished job now'

Thanks

Comment: So the command you're trying to execute is ''?

Comment: Assuming your call to `subprocess` is actually right (what you posted will give you a Python `OSError`) it depends on the implementation of the script. The error codes change depending on the implementation.

Comment: The meaning of the return code is defined by the command executed, not `check_call`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I've tried typing in the command directly into the shell but that simply returns 'qsub: Job rejected by all possible destinations' I understand that this is a problem with what I'm trying to do in unix but I thought that I was using check_call to get the exit code to tell me what's wrong, which is what I can't work out.

Comment: Then error 191 is probably the numeric error code for the error message you get from the interactive invocation. Without more information about `qsub` we can't know, either. Which vendor and version? Does it have a manual page? Online?

Comment: Apparently, page 211ff of http://resources.altair.com/pbs/documentation/support/PBSProRefGuide12.2.pdf ... But it simply states that nonzero means failure.

Comment: The cluster's a custom built system for the university, on the webpage it states that the system is Beowulf-class. The login node works using Linux through a SSH secure shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit code 191 indicates that the project code associated with the job is invalid. This is the code in line 13:-

> #PBS -P HPCA-000974-EFG

Which tells the cluster which project the code is associated with.